# MySQL Foreign Key to different table depending on column

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure the proper terminology for this type of relationship or even if it's good or bad. Hopefully I can clear up the lousy title.

I have a table that has the following fields:

```
id(pk), type, data(fk)
```

I want to be able to change the table that data points to depending on what "type" is. Depending on the type, there might be different types of data I need to pull. I'm basically trying to create a variable relationship.

Comment: you can delete the keys, alter the datatype and recreate them again.

Comment: What are you aiming to achieve by using a foreign key?

Comment: @user3056839 I'm trying to avoid adding a bunch of columns to a table that don't relate to everything being put into the table. So "typea" might utilize 3 common columns, then have 6 different columns. "Typeb" might utilize those same common columns and then have to have null values for the rest because they aren't in any way used by that type.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in MySQL.  You want conditional relationships.

You have basically three choices.

1. You can ignore putting these relationships in the database.
2. You can use `before insert` and `before update` triggers to enforce the constraints.
3. You can add a separate column for each type of id and add the constraints to those columns.

Comment: What is your use case, @Veo? Depending on what you need, either #2 or #3 could be the better option.

Comment: Basically I have a table of events. There are all types of events, however, each event type has different properties. I still want to be able to list all events in the same table but I'd rather not have a bunch of "extra" columns as they don't relate to all events. So I figured a conditional relationship would work - but didn't know if it was even possible.

Comment: So, you have multiple 'event' tables? Could you consolidate these into one table?

Comment: Well I'd have one 'event' table. That's sort of the issue. Event 1 has eight properties, Event 2 has 2 properties that aren't common to Event 1. So putting them into the same table would result in 10 columns, with 8 nulled fields for Event 2, and 2 nulled columns for Event 1. Which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Veo . . . That may not be a big deal.  If the 8 NULL-valued columns are `varchars()`, they will occupy very little space in each record.